# Setting global DNS via systemd-resolve CLI

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

Is there any way to set a global (not per interface) DNS server using the systemd-resolve command line tool? From the help it does not seem like this (--set-dns requires an interface). The usecase I have is that I have a lot of network interfaces and I want to set the same DNS on all of the interfaces.

Custom OS (Yocto), not using NetworkManager or anything.